# So many parentheses in gcc standard headers

Tags: c, gcc, macros

Why are constant expressions in GCC header files surrounded by parentheses, like this?

```
#define INTMAX_MIN (-9223372036854775807LL)
#define INTMAX_MAX (9223372036854775807LL)
```

What would be the difference if I omit parentheses, this way?

```
#define INTMAX_MIN -9223372036854775807LL
#define INTMAX_MAX 9223372036854775807LL
```

And why is there the 'L' suffix? Would it be the very same if I write the following?

```
#define INTMAX_MIN -9223372036854775807
#define INTMAX_MAX 9223372036854775807
```

Is there an actual usefulness or is it always the same thing?

I'm aware that the 'L' stands for long and I'm also well aware of the importance of parentheses in C macros; I'm asking this for the sake of curiosity.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

If you wrote

```
a = 7 INTMAX_MIN;
```

you would expect to get a syntax error, because on the face of it that would be an illegal expression. And it will, because it expands to

```
a = 7 (-9223372036854775807LL);
```

which does indeed give you a syntax error. But without the parentheses it would expand to:

```
a = 7 -9223372036854775807LL;
```

which doesn't give you an error, despite being obviously not what you intended.

More generally, all of these defines give expansions for things that look like identifiers. In an arithmetic expression, an identifier is a "primary expression", but -9223372036854775807LL is not. However, a parenthesized expression is a "primary expression".

And that's the real reason. So that the macro expands what *looks like* a primary expression to something that *is* a primary expression. You will never be surprised by what happens. In programming, surprise is usually bad.

Usually it doesn't matter, but the people who wrote the defines don't want them to usually work. They want them to always work.

The trailing LL marks this integer literal as of type `long long`, which is typically (and in this case is) 64 bits. Without the LL suffix, the literal could be interpreted as int, long int, or long long int, whichever is the first to support 64-bit values. Nailing down the type can be as important as nailing down the value.

Comment: You might also discuss `a = 7-INT_MAX;` with and without parentheses around `INT_MAX`, noting that the result would be different from `a = 7 - INT_MAX;`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler How would the result be different? You shouldn't need parentheses for `INT_MAX` since an integer literal is a primary expression.

Comment: @EricMSchmidt: _…blah, blah…_  **…Unless…** Oh drat! The original separate preprocessor process tended to give one answer, but the modern (as in 1989 or later) version tokenizes the input and the input stays tokenized, so `#define X -7` and `int main(void) { int x = 7-X; return x; }` yields a program that exits with status 14.  I should have remembered.

Comment: "the literal would be interpreted as an ordinary integer" is incorrect as @mafso comments.  Try `printf("%zu\n", sizeof (9223372036854775807));`

Comment: @mafso: That's not entirely correct from the language point of view. The only standard version of C language that allowed using *unsigned* types for suffix-less constants was C89/90. This functionality was outlawed in C99. Suffix-less constants can only have *signed* types. If the constant does not fit into the largest signed type the behavior is undefined. I.e. the language does not support using `unsigned long long` for a suffix-less constant.

Comment: @AndreyT  mafso comment is good if we strike the the "`unsigned long long`" and use  "Without the suffix, the type of the integer literal is the first of `int`, `long`, `long long`, which can hold the value." Having an "extended integer type" is another consideration.  BTW: it is "Suffix-less _decimal_ constants that must be signed.

Comment: here is the practical reason to place parens around parameters in #define macros:  given: #define number(x,y) x*x+y*y  Then the actual invocation of the macros is int result = number(10+20,5+6);  which expands to: result = 10+20*10+20+5+6*5+6;  which is obviously not correct.  However, if parens are used: #define number(x,y) (x)*(x)+(y)*(y) then it would expand to (10+20)*(10+20)+(5+6)*(5+6) which is correct.  This kind of problem occurs often in real programing and is the reason for the parens

Comment: @JonathanLeffler can you elaborate why `a = 7-INT_MAX;` and `a = 7 - INT_MAX;` return different results?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: I retracted that claim with my response comment to Eric Schmidt.

Answer (score 18):

It's a good practice to put parentheses on a macro with a integer constant and a unary operator like this:

```
#define BLA (-1)
```

as unary operators (`-` here) don't have the highest precedence in C. Postfix operators have higher precedence than unary operators. Remember that C doesn't have negative constants, for example `-1` is a constant expression preceded with the `-` unary operator.

As an aside PC-Lint suggest parenthesizes in such macros:

> (rule 973): parentheser #define N (-1)
>   Unary operator in macro 'Symbol' not parenthesized -- A unary
>   operator appearing in an expression-like macro was found to be not parenthesized. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> #define N -1
> ```
>
> The user may prefer to parenthesize such things as:
>
> ```
> #define N (-1)
> ```

Answer (score 12):

This answer attempts to show why the `LL` is needed. (It is not easy.) 
Other answers have shown why parentheses are needed.

Let's code three macros, all are *decimal constants*.

```
#define MAXILL (9223372036854775807LL)
#define MAXIL  (9223372036854775807L)
#define MAXI   (9223372036854775807)
```

Even though `MAXI` has no suffix, that does not make it type `int`. `MAXI` will have the first type it fits in, either `int`, `long`, `long long` or an extended integer type.

Even though `MAXIL` has the `L` suffix, it will have the first type it fits in, either `long`, `long long` or an extended integer type.

Even though `MAXILL` has the `LL` suffix, it will have the first type it fits in, either `long long` or an extended integer type.

In every case, the macros have the same value, but *potentially* different types.

See C11dr §6.4.4.1 5 for type determination.

---

Let's try printing them and have `int` and `long` are 32-bit and `long long` and `intmax_t` are 64.

```
printf("I   %d %d %d",       MAXI, MAXIL, MAXILL);    //Error: type mismatch
printf("LI  %ld %ld %ld",    MAXI, MAXIL, MAXILL);    //Error: type mismatch
printf("LLI %lld %lld %lld", MAXI, MAXIL, MAXILL);    //Ok
```

All three in the last line are correct as all three macros are `long long`, the preceding have type mis-matches between format specifier and the number.

If we have `int` is 32-bit and `long`, `long long` and `intmax_t` are 64, then the following are correct.

```
printf("LI  %ld %ld",    MAXI, MAXIL);
printf("LLI %lld", MAXILL);
```

The maximum width integer type has a format specifier of `"%" PRIdMAX`. This macro cannot expand to `"%ld"` *and* `"%lld"` to accommodate `MAXI, MAXIL, MAXILL`. It is set to `"%lld"` and numbers related to `intmax_t` need to have the same type. In this case, `long long` and only form `MAXILL` should be used.

---

Other implementations could have an extended integer type (like `int128_t`), in which case an implementation specific suffix or some mechanism could be used.

Comment: As a note, with C11 `_Generic` (and before with the popular `typeof` extension) types have become easier observable. (In C99 without extensions, I don't know how the difference between `long` and `long long` could be observed if they have the same size and representation;  given that it's OK if the implementation makes assumptions about calling conventions, and that it's quite unlikely that `long` and `long long` are passed differently, the question if the suffix is really needed for strict C99 remains.)